# Finding the standard matrix of a matrix transformation

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations

Given the matrix transformation :
T(x1,x2,x3) = (3x1+2x2+x3, -x1-x2)

How do I find the standard matrix for T?

My Thoughts:
T(1,0,0) = (3,-1)

T(0,1,0) = (2,-1)

T(0,0,1) = (1,0)

So as per my understanding the standard matrix will  be
A = 
[3  2  1]
    [-1 -1 0]

I am not sure if this is a correct answer

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Given the matrix transformation: $$T \left( \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 3x_1+2x_2+x_3\\-x_1-x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

We set up: $$[T] = T(e_1) + T(e_2) + T(e_3) $$
where, $$e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \space e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}, \space e_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence, following the $\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ transformation, we obtain:
$$[T] = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 2 & 1\\-1 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
**Note:** I know that this is a pretty old post, and that you have successfully found the answer, however I just want to illustrate the question in a more *mathematical* way, with proper matrices, etc (just to help those who have trouble comprehending the original post). Hope whoever see this have a good day!